# Как отправлять картинку при запросе

Tags: html

Помогите понять как работает отправка картинки при запросе. К примеру, GitHub отдает изображение, если путь к репозиторию корректный (https://github.com/microsoft/terminal).

Но вот недавно столкнулся с одним сайтом (nometa.xyz), и начал его редактировать, и увидел что сайт очень даже простой. Но несмотря на это, картинка (баннер) присылается, если вводить адрес в чатах.

Я это спрашиваю из-за того, что хочу убрать картинку с самого сайта, но функциональность отправки картинки осталось.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается это протокол Open Graph.

###### Основные Мета-данные:

```html
<meta property="og:url" content="<URL>"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="{article|website|profile|...}"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="<TITLE>"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="<DESCRIPTION>"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="<PATH>"/>
```

`og:url` – адрес вашей веб-страницы.
`og:type` – тип вашего сайта.
`og:title` – заголовок
`og:description` – описание
`og:image` – путь к изображению, к примеру: `https://<example.com>/<photo>.{jpg|...}`

Подробнее тут: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/, https://ogp.me и https://ruogp.me.

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)